# Is there any easy way to get the direct download link of all updates in ubuntu?

Tags: updates, update-manager

When a long list of new updates are available, I prefer to use a download manager in another computer to download .deb files of updates. Is there any easy way to get the direct download link of .deb files of all updates (from an update manager) in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the command line:

```
apt-get update
apt-get --print-uris upgrade
```

To extract the URLs from the output:

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes upgrade | awk '/^'\''/ {sub(/^./,"",$1); sub(/.$/,"",$1); print $1, $2}'
```

This snippet prints the URL for each package followed by the local file name. The local file name is usually the same as in the URL, but occasionally differs (I think only for packages whose version has an [epoch](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version)).

If you can run wget on the computer with the network connection, use [apt-zip](http://wiki.debian.org/AptZip) [image: Install apt-zip] which automates this task: it provides a tool that generates a shell script to perform the download, and a tool to import the downloaded packages. You can use that script even on a Windows machine, with a port of Unix tools such as [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: your second command shows lines of links with several .deb file name at the end. so all the .deb file are not changed into links. just some.

Comment: @CutieKrait I only did a smoke test, so my filter may well be wrong. I don't understand your problem report though. Can you give an example of it failing?

Comment: eg this is a line of the output: ## http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/ristretto/ristretto_0.6.3-1_i386.deb ristretto_0.6.3-1_i386.deb
    ## you see 2 .deb file only with one http://..

Comment: @CutieKrait That's what it's supposed to show! On each line, the first part is the URL, the second part is the local file name.

Comment: thanks, now I can download them using 'Free Download Manager'. Much easier and faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with synaptic,

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Click the buttons "Reload", "Mark All Upgrades", and then from the menu select File->Generate package download script.

Take the generated script and run it on another computer, and then use the menu option File->Add downloaded packages to install them, or do it manually with dpkg.