# How to find all dependencies not installed

Tags: software-installation

I have .deb file which is not updated for Ubuntu 13.10, it needs a lot of dependencies to be installed. How can I get a list of all its dependencies not installed in my Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: did  you installed that .deb file? If yes, then please provide the package name.

Comment: in a proper .deb file, the dependencies are defined and taken care of. isn't that the case?

Comment: @AvinashRaj this is the deb: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/86757101/gambas2-runtime_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb I want to get a list of dependencies which are needed to install it in 13.10 (and total size if possible)

Comment: its control file mentions: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11), libffi6 (>= 3.0.4), xdg-utils, do you have reasons to believe there are more? these are the dependencies that are installed automatically

Comment: @Jacob A few steps shows as if there is a long dependency well: `gambas2-gb-gui_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb`, then `gambas2-gb- qt_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb`, then `libqt3-mt-dev_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_i386.deb`, no more steps I tried..

Comment: did you try to run it? it installs without complaints :)

Comment: @Jacop: I think I have given the wrong to the runtime instead of gui link in previous comment, I meant this: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/86757083/gambas2-gb-gui_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb by the way the question is how to get the list of all dependencies, first level, second level, etc.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus can you please include all the relevant information in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try either `apt-cache showpkg <package-name>` or `dpkg -I <package.deb>`

Comment: the first does not work for the package. the second just show first level dependencies, but I need all dependencies I have to install before installing the deb.

Comment: "gdebi" may help you `sudo apt-get install gdebi-core` then `sudo gdebi <package.deb>`

Comment: they neither install nor give me a list of debs needed for http://launchpadlibrarian.net/86757083/gambas2-gb-gui_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb

Answer (score 1):

The most easiest approach is using gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi package.deb
```

It would install all dependencies you need.

Comment: The second does not install `gambas2-gb-qt_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb` which I have downloaded from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/86757083/gambas2-gb-gui_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb it just gives a name for another dependency, I have to search for the second and do the same, get another name and again search etc, too boring, I want to get all dependency names at once. The question is how to get the names of all dependencies needed by a (probably obsolete) deb not installed (in a list).

Comment: @MinimusHeximus what exactly are you trying to install and from where? Edit your question and include the information.

Comment: The question is about getting a dependency list for a deb in general. I think its more reasonable to ask another question for installing `gambas2-gb-qt_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb` (or gambas2 package in general in Ubuntu 13.10)

Comment: @MinimusHeximus in general, with a package that was included in some repository this will work, your package may need you to add a repository in which case I recommend you to follow the instructions.

Comment: I seems a solution is to find a repository containing that deb file and then something similar to what is stated in [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286118/is-there-any-easy-way-to-get-the-direct-download-link-of-all-updates-in-ubuntu) may work.